# Hide elements in a web page whilst using a web-browser control for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, browser

I am currently working on an app for WP7 for my university, and need a temporary solution to a problem. Now this solution is, that I will be loading a webpage using the web browser control for WP7. For example: http://m.iastate.edu/laundry/

Now as you see on the webpage, there are certain elements I want to hide, for example the back button. For now, what I have done to handle the back button is something like this:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle loading animations

    // Handle what happens when the "back" button is pressed
    Uri home = new Uri("http://m.iastate.edu/");

    // The the current loading address is home
    // Cancel the navigation, and go back to the 
    // apps home page.
    if (e.Uri.Equals(home))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

}
```

Now that works beautifully, except for the part that there is a back button on the hardware.

So my second option is to completely hide the back button **ONLY** on that page, and not its children. So **not** on http://m.iastate.edu/laundry/l/0

I am still debating on just parsing the data and displaying it in my own style, but I'm not sure if that's completely needed seeing how the data needs constant internet service and is already in a well-put format. Plus, I feel like that would be a waste of resources? Throw in your opinions on that too :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use InvokeScript and some js to hide it?

Comment: Well I'm still fairly new to programming, so haven't really played with js yet. I'm looking things up with InvokeScript, but would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject a script in the page with `InvokeScript`.

Here is the kind of Javascript code you need to remove the back button:

```
// get the first child element of the header
var backButton = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].firstChild;

// check if it looks like a back button
if(backButton && backButton.innerText == "Back") {
  // it looks like a back button, remove it
  document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].removeChild[backButton];
}
```

Call this script with InvokeScript:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "(function() { "+ script +"}()");
```

Warning: `IsScriptEnabled` must be set to `true` on the web control

If the removal of the back button depends of the page, just test the navigating URI in C# and inject the script if neeeded.